# How to get statics from Google analytics by Property ID (Not View ID)

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I make a request to get statistics for App by Property ID, I get an error that there is no permission for this profile. The profile was connected with firebase.

error code

```
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "errors": [ { "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions" } ] } }
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code as well it may help

Answer (score 0):

Remember the Google analytics API grants you access to extract data from Google analytics.   Adding a user to Firebase does not automatically grant access to Google analytics.

> "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

When you ran your code and authorized your application you did so with a user.  This user must have access to the **Google Analytics property Id** that you are sending.

The solution is to authorize your app with a user that within **Google Analytics** as at very least read only access or to grant this user read only access with from the **Google analytics** admin section.

The user needs to be added in [Google analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics) to use the Google analytics api not added in firebase

[image]

Comment: https://prnt.sc/26cgbr5 user has Analyst access but error still exist

Comment: Your still showing the user from firebase try https://analytics.google.com/ Make sure you are checking under the correct account.